# Configure RSpec to raise an error when calling DB in unit tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails, rspec3

Snappy tests, especially unit tests, should be written and there is no question about it. How do I configure RSpec to raise an error when a database hit is detected in a test tagged as `:unit`. This enforces the strategy of writing snappy tests and avoiding database hits when it's not necessary.

Right now, I have this code but it always raises an error, no matter what, even if I put a simple `puts "Hello"` in a test example.

```
config.around(:each, :unit) do |example|
  callback = lambda { |name, start, finish, message_id, payload|
    raise "Nope! Accessing the database in a unit test is not allowed!!\n\n Offending Query\n#{ payload[:sql] }"
  }
  ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribed(callback, "sql.active_record") do
    example.run
  end
end
```

```
RSpec.describe CategoryTranslationCreator, :unit do
  it 'creates a category translation' do
    puts "Testing..."
  end
end
```

raises

```
Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:

     1.1) Failure/Error: raise "Cannot access the database in a unit test!\n\n Offending Query\n#{"="*20}\n#{ payload[:sql] }"

          RuntimeError:
            Cannot access the database in a unit test!

             Offending Query
            ====================
            BEGIN
          # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:54:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # /home/jedrek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.7.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/transaction.rb:12:in `start'
          # /home/jedrek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.7.0/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:90:in `start'
          # /home/jedrek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.7.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:75:in `block in start'
          # /home/jedrek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.7.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:75:in `each'
          # /home/jedrek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.7.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:75:in `start'
          # ./spec/support/database_cleaner.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:57:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

     1.2) Failure/Error: raise "Cannot access the database in a unit test!\n\n Offending Query\n#{"="*20}\n#{ payload[:sql] }"

          RuntimeError:
            Cannot access the database in a unit test!

             Offending Query
            ====================
            SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace WHERE n.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false)) AND c.relkind IN ('r')
          # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:54:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # ./spec/support/database_cleaner.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:57:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```